# Axis value with different decimals in excel

Tags: excel

How can I have y axis values with 2 different decimals without using VBA? 
I have values in y axis `(0.01, 0.10, 1.00, 10.00, 100.00)`.
I want to change as follows ( to have 2 different decimals): `0.01, 0.10, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Y axis on your chart shows values that are in the vicinity of 100, then values in the vicinity of 0.01 will be pretty hard to spot.

Even values less than 10 will not show as a significant blip.  What difference does the Y axis label make for  units that are not showing, anyway?

If you want to make such fine a distinction, you will want to use two different charts from the outset.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your y-axis, then click Format Axis. Under Axis Options, check Logarithmic scale.